# Input con ancho dinámico no actualiza de forma automática

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos `input` separados por un `<hr>`, uno en la parte superior (con `id="nombre"`) y otro en la parte inferior (con `id="txt"`).

A medida que escribo en el `input` superior, se va escribiendo lo mismo en el `input` inferior, esto sucede en tiempo real.

El problema está en que, el `input` inferior debería tener un ancho dinámico, dependiendo de la cantidad de caracteres en su interior, pero solamente funciona si hago clic en dicho `input` (inferior).

```js
function resizable(el, factor) {
  var int = Number(factor) || 7.7;

  function resize() {
    el.style.width = ((el.value.length + 1) * int) + 'px'
  }
  var e = 'keyup,keypress,focus,blur,change'.split(',');
  for (var i in e) el.addEventListener(e[i], resize, false);
  resize();
}
resizable(document.getElementById('txt'), 7);

function fAgrega() {
  document.getElementById("txt").value = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px
}

input {
  min-width: 30px!important;
  max-width: 200px!important;
  transition: width 0.25s;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
Ingrese su nombre: <input id="nombre" type="text" onkeyup="fAgrega();" />

<hr> ¡Hola <input id="txt" type="text" class="preview_txt" onchange="resizable()" placeholder="you" />! Nos alegra tenerte aquí de nuevo.
```

Lo que intenté fue asignar la función del ancho dinámico con un evento `onchange`, para que el evento se ejecute cuando el usuario cambie el contenido del campo de entrada o `input`. Claramente no funciona. ¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias!

PD:
[Código en el que me basé](https://codepen.io/w3core/pen/DjLml).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2 cosas:

1. Siempre verifica que tengas un punto y coma al final de cada línea en javascript.
2. Si el evento de resize se tiene que dar en cada cambio del txt que tiene un onkeyup event, por lo tanto, dentro de esa función debe estar el resize.

Ejecuta el siguiente código:

```js
function resizable(el, factor) {
  var int = Number(factor) || 7.7;

  function resize() {
    el.style.width = ((el.value.length + 1) * int) + 'px';
  }
  var e = 'keyup,keypress,focus,blur,change'.split(',');
  for (var i in e) el.addEventListener(e[i], resize, false);
  resize();
}
resizable(document.getElementById('txt'), 7);

function fAgrega() {
  document.getElementById("txt").value = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  var element = document.getElementById("txt");
  resizable(element);
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px
}

input {
  min-width: 30px!important;
  max-width: 200px!important;
  transition: width 0.25s;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
Ingrese su nombre: <input id="nombre" type="text" onkeyup="fAgrega();" />

<hr> ¡Hola <input id="txt" type="text" class="preview_txt"  placeholder="you" />! Nos alegra tenerte aquí de nuevo.
```

Comment: El pistolero más rápido del desierto! Gracias fredyfx <3

Comment: En el desierto no hay gente xD!!!! Vale, con cariño Laura :3, que te vaya cheeere :D a seguir con todo el power 2.0!!!

Comment: quería decir del oeste jajaja me siento avergonzada

Comment: hahahahaha xD!!! lo sé :v descuida, es broma :D