# Problema al crear split de JS en input de texto

Tags: javascript

Gracias a la ayuda de [@fredyfx](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/287861/121407) en la [anterior pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/287854/input-con-ancho-din%C3%A1mico-no-actualiza-de-forma-autom%C3%A1tica), pude avanzar en lo que necesitaba. Ahora me encuentro ante el siguiente problema, necesito que en el `id="txt"` se introduzca solamente el primer nombre del usuario, para ello haría un split que detecta hasta el primer espacio en blanco `' '`, como lo haría en consola, por ejemplo:

```
var str = 'Pepito Perez'; 

var words = str.split(' '); 
console.log(words[0]);
```

Esto claramente me traería "Pepito", resultado el cual debo trasladar a mi segundo input, sin éxito.

Debería llamarlo como una función `string`? ¿Cómo debería convertirlo de `string` a `input`?

Gracias por su ayuda.

```js
function resizable(el, factor) {
  var int = Number(factor) || 7.7;

  function resize() {
    el.style.width = ((el.value.length + 1) * int) + 'px';
  }
  var e = 'keyup,keypress,focus,blur,change'.split(',');
  for (var i in e) el.addEventListener(e[i], resize, false);
  resize();
}
resizable(document.getElementById('txt'), 7);

function fAgrega() {
  document.getElementById("txt").value = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  var element = document.getElementById("txt");
  resizable(element);
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px
}

input {
  min-width: 30px!important;
  max-width: 200px!important;
  transition: width 0.25s;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
Ingrese su nombre: <input id="nombre" type="text" onkeyup="fAgrega();" />

<hr> ¡Hola <input id="txt" type="text" class="preview_txt"  placeholder="you" />! Nos alegra tenerte aquí de nuevo.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si te entendi bien, lo unico que necesitas es combinar los dos codigos.  Quedaria algo asi:

```js
function resizable(el, factor) {
  var int = Number(factor) || 7.7;

  function resize() {
    el.style.width = ((el.value.length + 1) * int) + 'px';
  }
  var e = 'keyup,keypress,focus,blur,change'.split(',');
  for (var i in e) el.addEventListener(e[i], resize, false);
  resize();
}
resizable(document.getElementById('txt'), 7);

function fAgrega() {
  var str = document.getElementById("nombre").value;

  var words = str.split(' ');   
  document.getElementById("txt").value = words[0];
  var element = document.getElementById("txt");
  resizable(element);
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px
}

input {
  min-width: 30px!important;
  max-width: 200px!important;
  transition: width 0.25s;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
Ingrese su nombre: <input id="nombre" type="text" onkeyup="fAgrega();" />

<hr> ¡Hola <input id="txt" type="text" class="preview_txt"  placeholder="you" />! Nos alegra tenerte aquí de nuevo.
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! Funciona aquí en el sitio, pero al llevarlo a mi proyecto deja de hacerlo, creo que es por un tema de ID's al momento de llamar las funciones, a lo mejor si le echas un vistazo a este pequeño pen puedas orientarme un poco mejor, gracias y siento la molestia https://codepen.io/LauraZ956/pen/VwZPgBB

Comment: El codigo del pen no es igual que el de mi respuesta.

Comment: Lo siento, ya lo he corregido con la ayuda de la comunidad en el chat :) Tu respuesta es correcta, el error era mio. Gracias por tu ayuda!